How to send Slack alert for a dbt 'warn' severity test using Airflow?
I have a dbt test setup for my dag which is modified to have a warn severity in its config like so:
{{ config(severity = 'warn') }}
Now the question is, once this test is ran during in airflow, how can I extract the WARN message thrown in the logs during the dbt test execution, and then send it to Slack using the SlackWebhookOperator?
I'm quite new with both technologies, but after looking around at docs and articles I still haven't found a perfect solution. Perhaps I'm missing something.
I've tried once running just the single test in its own dag, and it did send to Slack but I'm not sure whether it sent because the task was successful or because of the trigger_rule.ONE_FAILED, so I'm unsure. Any help would be appreciated.
